# How do I publish per-instance metrics in the AWS/EC2 namespace for Amazon CloudWatch?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, performance

I am in the process of publishing several custom metrics for CloudWatch.
When the metrics are on my own namespace, all goes well.
I now want to publish a per-instance metric, similar to `CPUUtilization`, with dimensions `ImageId=i-XXXXXXXX`, in the `AWS/EC2` namespace.
Unfortunately, CloudWatch disagrees with me and gives me this error:
*"The value AWS/ for parameter Namespace is invalid."*

- How do I add a custom metric to a specific instance?
- Is this possible at all?

many thanks,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The AWS/EC2 namespace is reserved for EC2 published metrics, so it's not possible. I'm sure I read it in the documentation but I can't find the source today.

Check the last post in this thread:
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=86835

Comment: You cannot specify a namespace that begins with "AWS/". Namespaces that begin with "AWS/" are reserved for use by Amazon Web Services products. For more information:  http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/APIReference/API_PutMetricData.html#Namespace

Comment: You definitely can, and your data will be added to e.g. EC2-related metrics but perhaps not in the dimension you expect.

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to figure this one our for myself. Issue like the namespaces/metricnames/dimensions not being defined well in the docs left me searching around for a bit.

Here is the script I was using, and at the detailed writeup, you can see the explication for what the terms mean and why things were done the way they were. I hope it helps others get this setup :)

[Detailed Writeup with examples/pictures/charts](http://www.lustforge.com/2012/07/22/custom-cloudwatch-metric-tutorial-freememory-and-cron/)

```
#setup variables
export AWS_CLOUDWATCH_HOME=/home/myuser/cloudwatch/CloudWatch-1.0.12.1
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jre1.6.0_33
export AWS_CREDENTIAL_FILE=$AWS_CLOUDWATCH_HOME/credential-file-path.template
 
# get free memory and send to AWS CloudWatch
FREEMEMKB=$(egrep -Eio "MemFree:\s*([0-9]*)" /proc/meminfo | egrep -Eio "[0-9]*")
echo `/home/myuser/cloudwatch/CloudWatch-1.0.12.1/mon-put-data --namespace="MySite" --metric-name=FreeMemory --dimensions="InstanceId=i-d889e31d" --unit=Kilobytes --value=$FREEMEMKB`
```

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I was looking for - the CloudWatch documentation is sorely lacking, and this is only one example. I'm using the Ruby aws-sdk to post custom metrics, and it works just the same.

Answer (score 0):

I've done it by

```
aws cloudwatch put-metric-data --namespace AWS/EC2 --dimensions \
InstanceID=$inst_id --metric-name test-sessions --value $cnt
```

The problem is the value is put not in `Per-Instance Metrics` but nearby and idk how to fix that:

[image]